# Tp Link on a Pi 1B

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-1

I am trying to set up an one RPi 1B with a Tp Link Archer T2U AC600 wifi adapter.

The Pi detects this adapter as a usb device,

and I have installed both the Realtek rtl8812au and the Mediatek MT7610U drivers to no avail.

I added each driver to /etc/modules when testing it.

I have recently updated to the 6.6.22+ kernel.

using "Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"

Is there some step that I am missing?
Any help is appriciated